# StringIO() argument 1 must be string or buffer, not cStringIO.StringIO

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, stringio, cstringio

I have a function that's reading a content object into a pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from cStringIO import StringIO, InputType

def create_df(content):
    assert content, "No content was provided, can't create dataframe"

    if not isinstance(content, InputType):
        content = StringIO(content)
    content.seek(0)
    return pd.read_csv(content)
```

However I keep getting the error `TypeError: StringIO() argument 1 must be string or buffer, not cStringIO.StringIO`

I checked the incoming type of the content prior to the StringIO() conversion inside the function and it's of type `str`.  Without the conversion I get an error that the str object does not have a seek function.  Any idea whats wrong here?

Comment: `InputType` is one of two types defined in `cStringIO`. Presumably you have a `OutputType` instance instead.

Comment: Strange, I changed it to OutputType and it worked.  But the same function was working with InputType before until I changed something in the code that I can't figure out what it was.  Thanks

Comment: That's because `StringIO('content')` creates `InputType` instances, while `StringIO()` (no argument) creates `OutputType` instances. You need to test *for both kinds*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only tested for `InputType`, which is a `cStringIO.StringIO()` instance that supports reading. You appear to have the *other* type, `OutputType`, the instance created for an instance that supports *writing* to:

```
>>> import cStringIO
>>> finput = cStringIO.StringIO('Hello world!')  # the input type, it has data ready to read
>>> finput
<cStringIO.StringI object at 0x1034397a0>
>>> isinstance(finput, cStringIO.InputType)
True
>>> foutput = cStringIO.StringIO()  # the output type, it is ready to receive data
>>> foutput
<cStringIO.StringO object at 0x102fb99d0>
>>> isinstance(foutput, cStringIO.OutputType)
True
```

You'd need to test for **both** types, just use a tuple of the two types as the second argument to `isinstance()`:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO, InputType, OutputType

if not isinstance(content, (InputType, OutputType)):
    content = StringIO(content)
```

or, and this is the *better* option, test for `read` and `seek` attributes, so you can also support regular files:

```
if not (hasattr(content, 'read') and hasattr(content, 'seek')):
    # if not a file object, assume it is a string and wrap it in an in-memory file.
    content = StringIO(content)
```

or you could just test for strings and [buffers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#buffer(, since those are the only two types that `StringIO()` can support:

```
if isinstance(content, (str, buffer)):
    # wrap strings into an in-memory file
    content = StringIO(content)
```

This has the added bonus that any other file object in the Python library, including compressed files and `tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile()` and `io.BytesIO()` will also be accepted and work.